# How to catch SIGERM, SIGINT from a process running pyzmq?

Tags: python, signals, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using PYZMQ and it seems I cannot catch SIGTERM anymore. How do I do that for a graceful handling of SIGTERM ?

Below is the code snippet:

```
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGTERM, SIGINT
from threading import Lock, Thread
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
import zmq


zmq_poller = None

class server(Thread, object):
    def __init__(self, transport):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.zmq_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PULL)
        self.zmq_socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 2000)
        self.zmq_socket.bind(transport)
        self.keep_running = True
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def process_data(self, data):
        data = self.decode(data)

    def decode(self, data):
        return pickle.loads(data)

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            try:
                data = self.zmq_socket.recv()
                self.process_data(data)
            except zmq.error.Again:
                pass
            except zmq.error as e:
                print e

    def stop(self):
        self.keep_running = False

def handle_stop(signum=None, frame=None):
    if zmq_poller:
        zmq_poller.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_stop)
    signal(SIGINT, handle_stop)
    mc = server('ipc:///tmp/abc')
    zmq_poller = mc
    mc.setDaemon(True)
    mc.start()
    mc.join()
    sleep(100)
```

As we see, the handle_stop signal handler is not invoked if I send SIGTERM, SIGINT to the process

Comment: Spawn the stuff you want done into a child thread and create a signal handler for the signals you want to handle.  Python can only handle signals to the parent thread so this will allow you to isolate the behavior of the child thread.  You will need to be careful about killing the child thread properly if it uses operating system resources such as locks etc.

Comment: Firstly this is a bad implementation of a `Thread`.  I don't think you should be sleeping on the parent for 100 seconds.  You need to wake the parent thread up in order to handle the signal.  I would avoid using daemons because they can result in poor or unexpected behavior.  I would check if the thread should die in the run() function and do a tiny sleep if any at all.

Comment: I would set the socket as blocking with a timeout, then at the end of each timeout you check if the child thread should die inside of run().  If the timeout is short you can end the program nicely.  You will need to schedule the parent thread in order to deal with your signal handlers so you cannot use sleep.  You should be spinning on the parent at some frequency.  I don't know if it's possible to catch the signals on a join().

Comment: @Matt The sleep for 100 seconds is just for testing purpose. In the production code, it won't be used that way

Comment: Since only the parent thread can catch the signal, and because your parent thread isn't scheduled, it cannot catch any signals.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that your main thread is blocked on `threading.Thread.join` [Execution of Python signal handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers):

> A Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C) signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode instruction)
>
> …
>
> A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.

Pre-3.3, the `signal` module definitely doesn't expose the tools you'd need to fix this problem yourself. So, if you can't upgrade to 3.3, the solution is to wait on something interruptible, like a `Condition` or an `Event`. The child thread notifies the event right before it quits, and the main thread waits on the event before it joins the child thread.